# Mixing datatypes, functions and objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

When you use `require` and loads a module, you seems capable of create a function with properties or a object that can be invoked as a function.

```
 console.log(require('events').EventEmitter);
 //{ [Function: EventEmitter] defaultMaxListeners: 10, listenerCount: [Function] }
```

I have done this before* using the `require` module so I can replicate it. But I want to create more manually. I have some questions in this regards:

1. Is possible replicate this manually, harcoded without `require`?
2. Is possible to create any type of property like getters or setters?
3. Is posible to create one of these 'objects' when you use a constructor?

Thanks in advance.

*Or I remember that, I have a terrible memory

**Edited**: 
To be clear: I'm not talking about `prototype`. In my example you can see that, for example, `defaultMaxListeners` dont come from prototype. In code:

```
 EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners // 10
 EventEmitter.prototype.defaultMaxListeners // undefined
 EventEmitter() //No error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is possible replicate this manually, harcoded without require? Is
> 2. possible to create any type of property like getters or setters? Is
> 3. posible to create one of these 'objects' when you use a constructor?

Yes

In JS, functions are also objects. You can attach properties to them like any other object. Also, in JS, functions can be used as both functions as well as object constructors.

The following example shows what you can do to a function. I'm using Classical OOP terms, since I don't know what they call them in JS.

```
function SomeConstructor(){
  this.instanceProperty = 'foo';
}

// Instance Method
SomeConstructor.prototype.method = function(){
  console.log('method');
}

// Static Method
SomeConstructor.staticMethod = function(){
  console.log('static');
}

var test = new SomeConstructor();
test.method();
SomeConstructor.staticMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have never read about it. It's a Javascript part that is somewhat obscure.

Comment: @bduran A good real-world example is jQuery, where you can call the `$` like a function `$(selector)`, yet use it like a namespace like `$.ajax()`.